# Flutter BottomNavigationBar call navigator push for one Navigator item

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation, bottomappbar

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` with 4 `BottomNavigaton` items and want 3 items to render different contents for the body, which works fine already. I want the first item to open the camera and link to a completely new page. How can I do this?

What I already tried is attached below.

I get errors like

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.

So I think I call the build method of CameraScreen too early, but I dont know how to avoid it.

```
class TabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      int index;
    
      TabScreen(this.index);
      @override
      _TabScreenState createState() => _TabScreenState(index);
   }

class _TabScreenState extends State<TabScreen> {
  int _selectedPageIndex;

  _TabScreenState([this._selectedPageIndex = 1]);

  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {
      // index = 0 should push new Screen without appbar & bottom nav bar and open camera
      'page': null,
      'title': 'Cam',
    },
    {
      'page': ListScreen(),
      'title': 'List',
    },
    {
      'page': TransportScreen(),
      'title': 'Transport',
    },
    {
      'page': ExportScreen(),
      'title': 'Export',
    }
  ]; 

void _selectPage(int index, BuildContext ctx) {
      setState(() {
          _selectedPageIndex = index;
      });
      // this part does not work
      // if (_selectedPageIndex == 0){
      //   Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(CameraScreen.routeName);
      // }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final bottomBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
      onTap: (i) => _selectPage(i, context),
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
          label: 'Cam',
          // backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.article_outlined),
          label: 'List',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.article_outlined),
          label: 'Transport',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          label: 'Export',
        ),
      ],
    );    

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 4,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: bottomBar,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: _buildActionButton(),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it myself. The above solution which uses `Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(CameraScreen.routeName);`
works indeed.

My problem was in the CameraScreen File, which used some Widgets in its build function and became too large to fit on the screen.